# Could not detect bluetooth device - qt.bluetooth.bluez received advertising error

Tags: linux, qt, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, qtbluetooth

I am using ubuntu 18.4, bluez 5.58. The bluetooth module is executed with 'root' privilege.
During power up of embedded device(using cypress BLE module), the advertising fails with error : "qt.bluetooth.bluez received advertising error". This issue happens intermittently.

I tried to restart the bluetooth module - /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart and call the advertise interface again. But the issue still happens.

```
<policy user="root">
    <allow own="org.bluez"/>
    <allow send_destination="org.bluez"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.Agent1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.MediaEndpoint1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.MediaPlayer1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.Profile1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.GattDescriptor1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.LEAdvertisement1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"/>
  </policy>
```

Does anybody know how to resolve this ? or Is there any retry mechanism to be implemented ?
Thank you.

Comment: Some more debug information would be helpful. To get Bluetooth debug information on Linux:

Are you able to power on the device using `bluetoothctl` on the command line?
Does `service bluetooth status` show errors?
When running your script have separate terminals open with the following running to get see the various logs:

`bluetootctl`, `journalctl -f -u bluetooth`, `sudo busctl monitor org.bluez`, and `sudo btmon`. If there are any error messages then please update your question with the new information